# Android change layout depending on if statement

Tags: android, if-statement, view, layout-inflater

Im trying to inflate a view depending on screen size so I can use different layouts

**I have tried the following**

```
double screen_size = 8

if screen_size >= 10 {
    layoutInflator =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
} 

if screen_size >= 5 && screen_size  <=9){
    layoutInflator =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylist2, parent, false);
} 

TextView textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

I get an error on the `Textview` saying `row` cannot be resolved even tho the `if` statement is being run

**If I change to**

```
double screen_size = 8

if screen_size >= 10 {
    layoutInflator =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylist2, parent, false);
} 

if screen_size >= 5 && screen_size  <=9){
    layoutInflator =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylist2, parent, false);
    } 

View row = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);

TextView textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

it runs fine but always runs layout `mylist` instead of `mylist2`

Any ideas where im going wrong

Any help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not casting it to View :

```
row = (View)layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylist2, parent, false);
```

Change the line to above line wherever your inflating views.

Comment: Thank You This Solved it But I had to declare row as well ie View row =null; Thanks as well to guys above for help

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `row` outside of the `if` statement, like this :

```
double screen_size = 8
View row = null;

if (screen_size >= 10 {
    layoutInflator =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylist2, parent, false);
} 

if (screen_size >= 5 && screen_size  <=9){
    layoutInflator =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylist2, parent, false);
} 

TextView textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: If I do this I get a Duplicate variable error in all if statements

Comment: Can you show me the full code? because it seems like you have already defined `row` variable outside of the `if` statement. 

If that's the case, you don't need to define `row` again below the `double screen_size = 8`. Just remove the variable declaration on the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

Declare the View globally and check. it will work

```
View row =null;

double screen_size = 8

if screen_size >= 10 {
    layoutInflator =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     row = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylist2, parent, false);
} 

if screen_size >= 5 && screen_size  <=9){
    layoutInflator =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     row = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylist2, parent, false);
    } 



TextView textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: If I do this I get a Duplicate variable error in all if statements

Comment: all if statement means, how many times your initializing view ?

Comment: Post your full code. so that i can solve your problem